# how to solve "implicit chunk serialization is disabled" error

Tags: omnet++, inet, mobility, simulte

I am working on a d2d communication in which I have used user1 sending packets to user2 using UDP, this worked well until I try to switch between IM to DM. Now I am getting following error.

> implicit chunk serialization is disabled.

I am using

- inet 4.2.5
- omnet 5.6.2
  Below is my code:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZJtC.png)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5TxJ.png)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpRvT.png)

Comment: What have you tried. provide some codes.